# List of dates between two tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

Problem

Input:

```
START_DATE      END_DATE 

01-FEB-16       03-FEB-16   
01-FEB-16       02-FEB-16 
10-FEB-16       11-FEB-16
```

I want to generate all the dates between the start_day and end_day as

```
Output

01-FEB-16    
02-FEB-16     
03-FEB-16     
10-FEB-16     
11-FEB-16
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/16207828/68868 for an answer to a similar question. Just add a distinct to the outermost select and you'll get unique dates.

Comment: See [**Row Generator**](https://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating dates between two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332130/generating-dates-between-two-columns)

Comment: Probably not a duplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it using **[Row Generator](https://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/)** technique.

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2    (START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE
  3    );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(DATE '2016-02-01', DATE '2016-02-03');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(DATE '2016-02-01', DATE '2016-02-02');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(DATE '2016-02-10', DATE '2016-02-11');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

**Query**

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(START_DATE+LEVEL-1, 'DD-MON-YYYY') the_date
  2  FROM t
  3    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= END_DATE-START_DATE+1
  4  ORDER BY the_date
  5  /

THE_DATE
-----------
01-FEB-2016
02-FEB-2016
03-FEB-2016
10-FEB-2016
11-FEB-2016

SQL>
```

Comment: @Abhishek What error? I have posted a working example. Copy paste your SQL*Plus session and show what exactly you are doing, just like I have shown you.

Comment: sorry buddy. It is working fine. Last time missed something while executing . Worked really hard for 2 days but didn't get the result. Finally I got. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Abhishek You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: One more thing. Suppose I want to check with one clause like "Where". How to do?

Comment: Instead of `from t` use a subquery. `from (select blah blah blah from t where...) connect by`

Comment: Please mark it as answered, there is a tick mark below the votes left side.

Comment: Working correctly if I am writing (Select  *  blah..blah.. from t where....).    Suppose I want to print a column name . How to do. Say I want to print a column called Name ,say something like this.                                                  SELECT Name,DISTINCT TO_CHAR(START_DATE+LEVEL-1, 'DD-MON-YYYY') the_date
  2  FROM t
  3    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= END_DATE-START_DATE+1
  4  ORDER BY the_date
  5                                                                                                                    The above query is giving error.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT name, TO_CHAR(START_DATE+LEVEL-1, 'DD-MON-YYYY') the_date
    FROM (select * from t where name = 'abc')
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= END_DATE-START_DATE+1
    ORDER BY the_date
    /`